# AnkhSVN prevent automatic merge

Tags: visual-studio-2010, svn, ankhsvn

I am using Visual Studio 2010 with AnkhSVN. I would like to prevent any automatic merging from taking place when I do an update. Is there a way to accomplish this?

Answer (score -1):

Please check if the below link helps you.

http://ankhsvn.open.collab.net/ds/viewMessage.do?dsMessageId=404446&dsForumId=582

Comment: Thanks. But nope, it doesn't help.